# resetting context in DialogFlow

Tags: ios, dialogflow-es

I want to be able to reset the context in my DialogFlow conversation. This is what I was trying:

```
func sendApiRequest(outgoing: String, isInitial: Bool) {
    let request = ApiAI.shared().textRequest()
    request?.query = [outgoing]

    if isInitial {
        let requestContext = AIRequestContext.init(name: "startup", andLifespan: 0, andParameters: nil)
        request?.requestContexts = [requestContext]
    }
    // (send and get response)
```

.. but this fails to reset the context. Is there a way?

Comment: What do you mean by "reset"?  Are you trying to remove a context from the conversational state?  If what lifespan does the `startup` context have in the example above after an intent is matched?  Are you saying that the Dialogflow still matches intents with the `startup` input context with the above request?  Contexts are just one input into Dialogflow's machine learning models and are not a guarantee that only intents with or without that context will be matched, you may need to look at your agent's structure and intent examples more closely.

Comment: The lifespans are 5 minutes, which makes sense in production, but when I'm developing, I would like to be able to 'reset' back to a virgin state every time I run the app

Comment: lifespan doesn't indicate minutes but turns in a conversation.  That being said, setting a context's lifetime to 0 should make that context's affect on your conversation state the same as if it never existed.  What behavior are you seeing that indicates the context is still active when you set the lifetime to 0?  Keep in mind that if other intents set this context again, that the context may be attached to your conversations state again.

Comment: Is there a way to set a context's lifetime to 0 in code? The (correct) behaviour is Q1 -> A1; Q2 - A2; etc. But if I restart the app after Q2 has been asked, I would like Q1 -> A1, but instead I get Q1 -> A2

Comment: The code you provide should work.  What behavior are you seeing that indicates that the context is not reset?  Please not that other intents that set an output context will override your query context definition after the intent is matched.

Comment: @coco is there any solution you get for reset context for IOS development?...same thing I want to do as you mention ...Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, @DhavalBhadania, I did not (and have moved on since then :)

Answer (score 2):

Using Node.js this works for us

```
//remove context by setting life span to 0
app.setContext(Input_Context_Remove, 0);

//set the output context to the next intent's input context with life span
app.setContext(Input_Context_Add, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reset all the contexts via the `DELETE /contexts` route.

Reference:
https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/contexts#delete_contexts

---

Since there are no real dialogflow iOS docs...
Have a look here:
https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-apple-client/blob/b4959a548c24094b0742dc77eda4381d32f35ec4/ApiAI/Classes/AITextRequest.m#L53